# calculating the coefficient of skewness for $f_Y(y) = e^{-y} ,y>0$

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I'm trying to find the coefficient of skewness for the pdf: $f_Y(y) = e^{-y}; y>0$

After having calculated for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ I get the values $(1, 1)$ respectively.

Then placing this into the equation for skewness:

$$\gamma = \frac{E[(X-\mu)^3]}{1} = \sum_{j=0}^{3} \binom3jE(Y^j)(-1^{3-j}).$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here, and having a look at the solution to this exercise I find that $E(Y^j) = j!$ why is this the case?

Comment: Is it $e^{-y}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the definition of [Coefficent of Skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness), it is

$$\frac{\hat{\mu}_3}{\sigma^3}$$

where $\hat{\mu}_3$ is the third central moment. Given that $\sigma^2=1$ your coefficient of skewness is

$$\int_0^{\infty}(y-1)^3e^{-y}dy=2$$